# Object[] cannot be converted to Integer[]

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Converting a TreeSet object to an array using the toArray method, however I get the error:
    `Object[] cannot be converted to Integer[]`

Here is the code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    TreeSet elems = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    int[] elemsToAdd = {1,2,3,4};

    for(int i = 0; i < elemsToAdd.length; i++){
        elems.add(elemsToAdd[i]);
    }
    Integer[] elemsArray = elems.toArray(new Integer[elems.size()]);
 }
```

I've searched other threads for the answer, however all of them recommend to use the toArray method with an Integer array as an argument yet mine still throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

That's due to your usage of raw type. When `elems` is defined as a raw `TreeSet`, `elems.toArray` returns an `Object[]`, not an `Integer[]`.

Change

```
TreeSet elems = new TreeSet<Integer>();
```

to

```
TreeSet<Integer> elems = new TreeSet<Integer>();
```

Comment: You don't really need the second Integer, `TreeSet<Integer> elems = new TreeSet<>();`

Answer (score 1):

Erans Answer solves the error but I would also like to make my contribution

`TreeSet<T>` takes in any Object type, Making it `TreeSet<Integer>` Would allow you to put `Integer` values inside the TreeSet, Heres how you can define it

```
TreeSet<Integer> elems = new TreeSet<>();
```

You are using a regular loop that can be replaced with a for-each in your case working example is

```
for (int anElemsToAdd : elemsToAdd) {
   elems.add(anElemsToAdd);
}
```

And lastly you don't need to define `new Integer[elems.size()]` with the size defining it as `elems.toArray(new Integer[0])` is sufficient

And after all the changes this is the final result

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeSet<Integer> elems = new TreeSet<>();
    int[] elemsToAdd = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    for (int anElemsToAdd : elemsToAdd) {
        elems.add(anElemsToAdd);
    }
    Integer[] elemsArray = elems.toArray(new Integer[0]);
}
```